# Perform groupping and averaging for the previous rows of DataFrame, except current

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I need to calculate a variable equal to the average value for the previous time. For example,
import pandas as pd

```
list_of_tuples = [('A', '2021-01-01', 1, np.nan),
                  ('A', '2021-01-02', 2, 1),
                  ('A', '2021-01-03', 3, 1.5),
                  ('A', '2021-01-04', 4, 2),
                  ('A', '2021-01-05', 5, 2.5),
                  ('B', '2021-01-01', 1, np.nan),
                  ('B', '2021-01-02', 2, 1),
                  ('B', '2021-01-03', 3, 1.5)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=list_of_tuples, columns=['ID', 'DATE', 'VALUE', 'RESULT'])


ID       DATE  VALUE  RESULT
 A 2021-01-01      1     NaN #no previous info
 A 2021-01-02      2     1.0 #== 1/1
 A 2021-01-03      3     1.5 #== (1 + 2)/2
 A 2021-01-04      4     2.0
 A 2021-01-05      5     2.5
 B 2021-01-01      1     NaN #no previous info
 B 2021-01-02      2     1.0 #== 1/1
 B 2021-01-03      3     1.5
```

in RESULT column each value is equal to average of VALUE in current group for the previous time

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates are sorted, you can `groupby` ID to compute the cumulated sum (`cumsum`), then divide by the row number (obtained with `cumcount`), finally `mask` the first values per group (row 0 per group):

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['VALUE']
count = g.cumcount()
df['RESULT'] = (g.cumsum().shift()/count).mask(count.eq(0))
```

output:

```
  ID        DATE  VALUE  RESULT
0  A  2021-01-01      1     NaN
1  A  2021-01-02      2     1.0
2  A  2021-01-03      3     1.5
3  A  2021-01-04      4     2.0
4  A  2021-01-05      5     2.5
5  B  2021-01-01      1     NaN
6  B  2021-01-02      2     1.0
7  B  2021-01-03      3     1.5
```